# How to create multi level menu using jade.pug

Tags: html, css, node.js, pug

In `header.pug`

```
block link
    -var selected='Home';
-var menu = [{'title':'Home','address':'/home/home.html','child':[]},{'title':'Shopping','address':'/shopping/shopping.html','child':[{'title':'TV','address':'/tv/tv.html'},{'title':'Smartphone','address':'/smartphone/smartphone.html'}]},{'title':'About','address':'/about/about.html','child':[]}]

#navbar
    +navbar(selected,menu)
```

In `mixin.pug`

```
//- Navbar mixin
mixin navbar(selected, menus)
            ul
                each menu in menus       
                    if selected === menu.title
                        li.active
                           a(href=menu.address, title=menu.address)= menu.title
                           if menu.child.length > 0
                                +navbar(selected, menu.child)
                    else
                        li
                           a(href=menu.address, title=menu.address)= menu.title
                           if menu.child.length > 0
                                +navbar(selected, menu.child)
```

**Problem:**

When compile it into html, there is a error, shown in the console:

```
Cannot read property of undefined in the "if menu.child.length > 0" row
```

**Edit:**

Added a picture:

[image]

Comment: Your child menu items don't have a `child`  array property. Either add `child: []` to each child item, or adjust your if statement to guard against absence of the property (I.e. `if menu.child && menu.child.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the data in `menu.child` when you call `+navbar(selected, menu.child)`. Objects in menu.child don't have a propety `child`, so when Pug try to get the length of this undefined values the error appears.

1. Add `child` property inside objects in array `menu.child`.
2. Or modify a little bit your code to change if `menu.child` is not undefined (I assume you don't want to, because objects without `child` property will not be displayed:

   ```
   if typeof menu.child == typeof []
       if menu.child.length > 0
           +navbar(selected, menu.child)
   ```

Comment: Thanks @dzej.5. I used your second option. It worked.